# How I can use HTML and CSS Tags with a C# Event?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css, events

net application and I want to create me a own Button with css and html and use the onclick event for execute c# code. But I get the error:

```
Runtimeerror in Microsoft JScript: "BtnAdd_Click" is undefine
```

Here is my Code:

ASPX file:

```
<div id="GuestListViewControls">
                <table>
                    <td><a href="#" class="GuestButtons" runat="server" onclick="BtnAdd_Click">Hinzufügen</a></td>
                </table>
               </div>
```

My C#:

```
protected void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            Response.Write("Add");
        }
```

Can I use this Button with C# Code in a ASP.NET Application? :/

Comment: Your aspx is incorrect. You need to add a `<tr>` above `<td>` and close it just before `</table>`.

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem...and it works without <tr>, too; ;-)

Comment: That doesn't mean that you can ignore the markup.

Comment: i add the <tr> tag now ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a c# error, It's like a *javascript* error , Now  You can use *LinkButton* for *onclick* event, It's look like also anchor tag

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="MyLink" runat="server" class="GuestButtons" OnClick="BtnAdd_Click" Text="Click Here"></asp:LinkButton>
```

or use onserverclick event instead of onclick event

```
<a href="#" runat="server"  class="GuestButtons" onserverclick="BtnAdd_Click">test</a>
```

Comment: @RameshRajendran it can be done with anchor tag only.

Comment: @Rex , Yes we can use onserverclick ! But if the OP must need to Onclick event, The he can use linkbutton !

Answer (score 2):

You are using "A" tag. This is HTML Anchor control and it does not support server side event.

Use

```
<asp:Button id="mybutton" Text="Submit" runat="server" onclick="BtnAdd_Click" />
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can do it using HTML controls only 
you just need to use on `onserverclick`**

**Sample Test stuff**

```
<a href="#" runat="server" onserverclick="anchorclick">test</a>

code behind

protected void anchorclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // do stuff here
}
```

**See Refrence**

[HTML Anchor Server Side Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlanchor.onserverclick.aspx)

[HTML Button Click Server Side](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlbutton.onserverclick.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error:

```
Runtimeerror in Microsoft JScript: "BtnAdd_Click" is undefined
```

Because you're using an onclick event on an HTML anchor tag.

You need to use an asp:Button tag instead, for which the onclick event will point to a server-side method. Something like this:

```
<asp:Button class="GuestButtons" runat="server" onclick="BtnAdd_Click" text="Hinzufügen"></asp:Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting "Runtimeerror in Microsoft JScript: "BtnAdd_Click" is undefine" because onclick searches for the method in the Javascript.

One option would be have a javascript method on the href click and from that method you can invoke the server side method using Ajax post or get or simple .Ajax

Please refer solution 4 in the url http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/334635/how-to-call-a-csharp-function-in-a-href-onclick-ev